# How to handle pop ups automatically - SELENIUM+PYTHON

Tags: python, selenium

How can I handle pop ups in a web page (while web application testing) to automatically execute itself when it detects any pop-up dialog?

> (This is meant to occur at any instance like upon a button click, (or) soon as 
>   a page is opened, (or) happens upon a button click etc. Which means we don't know if the dialog box will show or not.
>
> The idea is to automatically deal with such issues while testing any web application.

[image]
[image]

As shown in the two images, for instance if I click on 'Deliver to' anchor tag, the modal window will pop-up. Clicking on the link was done but the issue that i face is:

- Needs to know whether I need to handle a pop-up upon clicking the link or something else. How to know what is the next step? Not just for amazon.in (as shown here), but to generalize (any URL).
- If pop-up (as shown) how to handle this? As i tried to handle alert boxes
  `alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert`
  `alert.accept()`
  I tried to handle windows for the same. But nothing seems right!

I will share the link of the example I have quoted. I think the same can be accessed from any domain and i guess the coding will be the same.
https://www.amazon.in/b/ref=2017Diwali_wave2_shopalldeals_atf?node=3419926031

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @DebanjanB I'm sorry but I have updated my question and I have tried to be more specific on the same.

Comment: It's neither a `pop-up dialog` nor an `alert`. It's a Modal Dialog Box stemming out from the `HTML DOM`. Handle it as a regular node.

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks! I followed the DOM and had understood it was a Modal Dialog. What I meant is that I wanted a way to automatically identify any of such kinds - be it `pop-up dialog`, `alert`, `modal dialog` etc (sorry if i was not clear). I am trying to automate the situations that kind of run in to these.

And the `alert` code I specified was to show that i tried all the ways I knew so far.

Comment: I tried your usecase. When I click on `Add to Cart` I am redirected to `Login Page`. Can you update your exact manual steps along with your code block?

Comment: @DebanjanB It was not `Add to Cart` which I had pointed to in the example above. It was `Deliver to` in the top left corner (navigation bar). One thing is that I cannot share the code as it is work-related and I'm sorry! My objective is quite broad as to test the whole website automatically upon the only input which is the URL of the website. So testing the whole website automatically means it should jump all possible hurdles. (1/2)

Comment: Page redirections are caught and tested the usual way as I use a case of recursion. But the major hurdle I face now is the events such as `modal window`, `pop-up dialog` etc that should be handled upon an action of `button click` etc. Could there be some way like, `if i click on a button and then see what action occurs and then handle the action`. The major point to note hear is that every thing should be some kind of automation and not application specific. (2/2)

Answer (score 0):

`JavascriptExecutor` can works for you. Just take care that you should execute it before clicking the event which invoke alert.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
```

Note :- do not use it after clicking on event which invoke alert confirmation box. Above code by default set the confirmation box as true means you are accepting/click on ok on all confirmation box on that webdriver session if invoked.